# WordPress Send Email Content as .HTML attachment

Tags: php, wordpress, html-email, email-attachments

I have an email that has HTML content in it that is not suitable for email standards. Meaning it has markup that is not valid in email standards.

I need to send this content/PHP variable as an HTML file instead of as email body content. I'm using wp_mail. I simply want to take the $template variable and make it an html file somehow and send it off. Below is the simple wp_mail function that I'm using. Again, I need to use the $template variable and somehow generate an HTML file out of it.

file_put_contents is not an option.

```
wp_mail($to, $subject, $template, $headers, $mail_attachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about 
$myfile = fopen('myHTMLFile.html', 'w');

And with fwrite() you put your content in it and send it.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider `wp_upload_bits`to create the template file since `wp_mail`only accepts files for attachments:

```
$html_file = wp_upload_bits('test.html', null, $template);
```

and then call `wp_mail`to send the html attached:

```
wp_mail($to, $subject, 'your message', array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;'), array($html_file['file']) );
```

Don't forget to check the `$html_file` object, `$html_file['error']` must be false.

Finally you can delete the file from the server:

```
unlink( $html_file['file'])
```

Hope this helps!